# Wordpress - Post loop with posts from two categories with different layouts

Tags: wordpress

I want to display posts from two different categories in WordPress. The categories should have their own styles. But I can't make it work properly. The post appears but not in date order or limited to five posts.

Below you can find a excerpt from my code.

Thanks

```
<ul class="slides">
<?php query_posts('cat=13,5&orderby=date&posts_per_page=5'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<?php if ( is_category('13') ) {?>
    <li>                    
        <div>
            CONTENT    
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php } else {?>
    <li>                    
        <div>
            CONTENT    
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php }?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/is_category) checks the template not a post. You need [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
var_dump($categories);
```

Thanks